# How can i choose indian currency Rupee in opencart storefront?

Tags: e-commerce, opencart, currency, storefront

I have inserted indian rupee in database table. But still i don't know, why in store front currency drop-down indian rupee currency is not displayed. Please let me know hot to add a specific currency ? Thanks in Advance
 [image: Adding the Indian Rupee in Database Table]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you've added this in the database instead of through the admin, it's likely that the cache file still exists for the currencies. Go to the `/system/cache/` directory and find any files starting `cache.currency` and delete them. Alternatively just edit the currency in the store admin. This is actually how you should do this, not mess around with the database tables

Answer (score 3):

It works to me
 Steps
1. Go to `System -> Localisation -> Currencies`

2. Add Currency Title as `Rupees`
3. Code as `INR`
4. Symbol Left as `₹`
5. Decimal Places as `2`
6. Value as `1.00000000`
7. Status as `Enable`

Now, you need to Go to

1. `System -> Settings -> Your Store -> Action -> Edit`
2. Get `Local` and Edit
3. Country as `India`
4. Region / State as `select any state of india`
5. Language as `English`
6. Administration Language as `English`
7. Currency as `Rupees`
8. Auto Update Currency as `Yes`
9. Define your Length and Weight class as you required

Again Got to

1. `System -> Localisation -> Currencies`
2. You will get Rupees as `Default`
3. Delete `USD` and
4. Click on your `Dashboard` that is on the left bar
5. You will find `setting` symbol on right side top corner.
6. Click on that and you will get `CACHE`
7. Click on `OFF` and on `Action` do `REFRESH`

You are done.

Thanks.